# Regex: match characterclass but not a specified string

Tags: regex

I am doing some major refactoring.

```
[a-z_]*(->|::)[sg]et_source\s*\(
```

matches anything like

```
$this->get_source() 
$foobar->set_source ($x)
self::get_source()
```

Now I want to exclude a specific class, say I want the [a-z_]* part NOT to match "foobar", e.g.

```
foobar::get_source()
$foobar->get_source()
```

Is there an AND operator withhin the [], or do I need some negative lookbehind?

EDIT: I am not parsing nor validating code, so no security concerns here. That´s gonna be a temporal precommit hook to warn about method calls considerd deprecated after the refactor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you mean `(?:->|::)`. The expression you have matches any one character out of `-`, `>`, `|`, or `:`.

Comment: Also the `[a-z_]*` is completely redundant, since you allow it to match zero times. Maybe take out the `*` to force (at least) one character to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind like this:

```
[a-z_]+(?<!foobar)(->|::)[sg]et_source\s*\(
```

also note that in the alternation part, `->|::`, you should not use a character class.

Comment: Thank you, nice straight-forward answer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would build matcher groups and process the not condition in code.

```
([a-z_])*[->|::][sg]et_source\s*\(
```

Then in my language of choice (note the parens around the group in question):

```
if $1 == foobar then exclude
```

I've always found regexes to be better at expressing what you want to match rather than what you want to exclude.

However, you could look into negative lookaheads if your regex engine supports that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew White, you should do that outside the regex.

BTW your regex is not totally correct. Change it to:

```
[a-z_]+(?:\->|::)[sg]et_source\s*\(
```